# button not showing animation effects

Tags: button, uibutton, extjs

I am using a panel which contains a toolbar with three buttons.

This panel is loaded in 2 diff files.

The first file that its loaded it shows proper gradient effects when the button is pressed or released but the other panel shows no effects at al. The buttons still work but the style is not there.

is it over written by some other file?

my panel is:

```
config:{
        navigationBar: {
            hidden:'true'

        },
        items:[
            {
                xtype:'toolbar',
                layout:'hbox',
                height:70,
                width:310,
                activeItem:2,
                items:[
                    {
                        xtype:'button',
                        iconCls:'note_black',
                        iconAlign:'top',
                        text:'Workitems',
                        iconMask:true,
                        ui:'normal',
                        id:'workitem',
                       // enableToggle:true,
                        enabled:true,
                        disabled:false,
                        top:5,
                        height:60,
                        handler:function () {
                        //  Ext.getCmp('workitem').setUi('toggle');
                        //  Ext.getCmp('workitem').toggle(true,true);
                            //Ext.getCmp('workitem').toggle(false,true);
            //              Ext.getCmp('workitem').setPressed(0);
                            //Ext.getCmp('workitem').addCls('button_pressed');
                        }

                    },
                    {
                        xtype:'button',
                        iconCls:'inbox2',
                        iconAlign:'top',
                        text:'Inbox Queue',
                        iconMask:true,
                        ui:'normal',
                        id:'inbox',
                        top:5,
                        height:60,
                        enabled:true,
                        disabled:false,
                        left:93,
                        handler:function () {

                        }

                    },
                    {
                        xtype:'button',
                        iconCls:'doc_drawer',
                        iconAlign:'top',
                        text:'File Cabinet',
                        enabled:true,
                        disabled:false,
                        iconMask:true,
                        ui:'normal',
                        id:'filecabinet',
                        top:5,
                        height:60,
                        left:200,
                        handler:function () {
                        }

                    }]
            }]
    }
```

and m loading it in 2 diff files with the same code that says

```
{
      xtype:'bottomBarPanel'
 },
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because i was trying to use the same panel in 2 different places. Appartently you cant do that. So i created separate panels for the 2 files and its working fine now.